# In ASP.NET 4.8, how can I deserilize a file containing JSON, uploaded as POST multipart/form-data request to an object in memory (no file on server)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

Example code:

I export an object as JSON in a file

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult ExportObjectToFile()
{
    var exampleObject = new ExampleObject();

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, exampleObject, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(DispositionTypeNames.Attachment)
    {
        FileName = exampleObject.FileName;
    };

    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

Now I want to import and create a new object using multipart/form-data on Postman to attach the file with the request

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ImportObjectFromFile()
{
    var multipartForm = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var jsonString = await multipartForm.Contents[0].ReadAsString().ConfigureAwait(false);

    var importedExampleObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<exampleObject>(jsonString);

    return ResponseMessage(importedExampleObject);
}
```

I know it's considered bad practice to not store the file first locally but this is more of a learning exercise for me, it helps me understand how file uploads work.

So with the above code `importedExampleObject` is created but all the fields are null, essentially all the data is lost, and there are no exceptions thrown, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: What is the variable `tmp`? What is the value in `jsonString`?

Comment: Hey @vernou sorry that was a typo

Comment: @vernou the value is the JSON, I checked in the debugger and it's the proper JSON from the export

Comment: Can you show the json content and the class `PreparerProfile`?

Comment: @vernou that's another typo sorry! I corrected it. Anything really in ExampleObject, I get the same results.

Comment: Can you show the value in `exampleObject` and the class `exampleObject`?